# Save document after subdocument been updated mongoose, mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I want to update a subdocument's value and after that save the main document. So the changes to the subdocument gets saved to the database.
Here is my code ATM,
I find the correct subdocument, that is not the problem I guess. But it doesn't save the changes.

```
 projectModel.findById({_id: req.body.projectId})
  .then(function(doc){

    question = doc.qp.questions.filter(q => {return q._id == req.body.questionId})[0];

    var ans = question.answers.filter(a => {return a._id == req.body.answerId})[0];
    if(ans)
    {console.log(ans)}
    ans.value = req.body.answerValue;

    doc.save().then(res.send({questionId: req.body.questionId,answerId: req.body.answerId,answerValue: req.body.answerValue}))

  })
  .catch(error => console.log(error))
```

my object is kinda complex, and it has to be.. it looks something like this:

```
project={
         prop,
         prop,
         prop, 
         qp:{
             prop,
             prop,
             prop, 
             questions:[
                        question:{
                                  prop,
                                  prop,
                                  prop, 
                                  answers:[
                                           answerModels<--!this i want to find and edit!-->
                                          ]
                                 }
                        ]
            }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You should consider [FindOneAndUpdate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#findoneandupdate_findOneAndUpdate) function of Mongoose.

This will allow you to find your document, edit it and save it back in your MongoDB.

Comment: Yeah I tried that but I didn't get it to work, you see my object is kinda complex
project={prop,prop,prop, qp:{prop,prop,prop, questions:[question:{prop,prop,prop, answers:[answerModels<--!this i want to find and edit!-->]}]}}

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this:

```
projectModel.findById({_id: req.body.projectId},function (err, doc)
  {
    if(err)
    {
      console.log(err)
      return;
    }
    for (i in doc.qp.questions) {
      if(doc.qp.questions[i]._id == req.body.questionId)
      {
        for(y in doc.qp.questions[i].answers)
        {
          if(doc.qp.questions[i].answers[y]._id == req.body.answerId)
          {
            var test = doc.qp.questions[i].answers[y].value
            console.log(test);
            var query = "qp.questions"+i+"answers."+y+".value";

            doc.update({_id: req.body.questionId}, { '$set': {query : req.body.answerValue} });
            console.log(doc.qp.questions[i].answers[y].value);
            doc.save().then(() => res.send({questionId: req.body.questionId,answerId: req.body.answerId,answerValue: req.body.answerValue}))
          }
        }
      }
    }
  })
  .catch(error => console.log(error))
```